# Dropdown not working on parent child selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

> I have created a dependent dropdown in my project ,whenever i select
>   parent dropdown its dependent child dropdown showing but when i
>   change the parent dropdown all the child dropdown  gets mixed with the previous parent.

```
<body>
<h1><p>Lab Cost</p></h1><br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="labCat" id="labC" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Lab Category</option>
                    @if(isset($lab_category))
                        @foreach($lab_category as $lb)
                            <option value="{{$lb->lab_category_id}}">{{$lb->category_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="labSub" id="labS" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Lab Sub Category</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="labTest" id="labT" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Lab Test</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><span id="loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-3x fa-spin"></i></span></div>
    </div>

</div>
<div>
    <p id="testCost"></p>
</div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#labC').on('change', function(){
        var labCategId = $(this).val();
        $('#labT').html('');
        $('#labT').append('<option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Lab Test</option>');
        if(labCategId) {
            $.ajax({
                processing : 'true',
                serverSide : 'true',
                url: 'get_lab_sub',
                type:"POST",
                data : {labCategId:labCategId,"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                dataType:"json",

                success:function(data) {
                    if(data){
                        $.each(data, function(key, value){
                            $('#labS').append('<option value="'+value.lab_sub_category_id+'">' + value.sub_category_name + '</option>');

                        });
                    }else {
                        $('#labS').empty();
                    }

                },

            });
        } else {
            $('select[name="labS"]').empty();
        }

    });

    $('#labS').on('change' ,function () {
        var labSubId = $(this).val();   
        if(labSubId){
            $.ajax({
                processing : 'true',
                serverSide : 'true',
                depends : ['#labC'],
                url :'get_lab_sub_cat',
                type:"POST",
                data :{ labSubId:labSubId,"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                dataType: "json",
                success:function (data) {
                    if(data){
                        $.each(data, function(key, value){
                            $('#labT').append('<option value="'+ value.lab_test_id +'">' + value.lab_name + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#labT').empty();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    })
   $('#labT').on('change' ,function () {
        var lab_test_cost_id = $(this).val();
        if(lab_test_cost_id){
            $.ajax({
                processing : 'true',
                serverSide : 'true',

                url :'get_lab_cost_rs',
                type:"POST",
                data :{ labtid:lab_test_cost_id,"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                dataType: "json",
                success:function (data) {
                    if(data){
                        $.each(data, function(key, value){
                            $('#testCost').append('<h5>The Lab Cost is </h5><p value="'+value.lab_test_id +'"> '+ value.cost + '</p>');
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
</body>
```

> controller

```
class Test extends Controller
{
        public function ex(Request $request){
            $table =  \DB::table('company')->select('name','type','address','city','email','description')->get();
            return $table;
        }

        public function cost(Request $request){
            $lab_data = \DB::table('lab_category')->select('lab_category_id','category_name')->get();
            return view('pages/medicinecost')->with('lab_category',$lab_data);
        }

        public function costSub(Request $request){
            $get_lab_cat_id = $request->get('labCategId');
            $lab_sub_data = \DB::table('lab_sub_category')
                ->leftJoin('lab_category','lab_category.lab_category_id','=','lab_sub_category.category_id')
                ->where('lab_category_id', $get_lab_cat_id)
                ->select('sub_category_name','lab_sub_category_id')->get();
            return $lab_sub_data;
        }

        public function costTest(Request $request){
            $get_lab_sub_id = $request->get('labSubId');
            $lab_test_data = \DB::table('lab_test')
                ->leftJoin('lab_sub_category','lab_sub_category.lab_sub_category_id'
                    ,'=','lab_test.sub_category_id')
                ->where('sub_category_id',$get_lab_sub_id)
                ->where('hide',0)
                ->select('lab_name','lab_test_id')->get();
            return $lab_test_data;
        }

        public function labTestprice(Request $request){
            $get_lab_test_id = $request->get('labtid');

            $cost = \DB::table('lab_test')
                ->leftJoin('lab_sub_category','lab_sub_category.lab_sub_category_id','=','lab_test.sub_category_id')
                ->where('lab_test_id',$get_lab_test_id)
                ->Where('hide',0)
                ->select('cost','lab_test_id')->get();
            //  dd($cost);
            return $cost;
        }
}
```

Whenever i changed the parent dropdown all the below 2 child dropdowns should be rese and also show the dependent child dropdowns on selection of parent category

Comment: Looking like up-voting contest.(same company people)[Software Engineering at Syntags Consultancy & Services Pvt. Ltd]

Answer (score 0):

> try this , i think this will your issue

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#labC').on('change', function(){
            var labCategId = $(this).val();
            $('#labS').html('');
            $('#labS').append('<option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Lab Sub Category</option>');
            $('#labT').html('');
            $('#labT').append('<option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Lab Test</option>');
            if(labCategId) {
                $.ajax({
                    processing : 'true',
                    serverSide : 'true',
                    url: 'get_lab_sub',
                    type:"POST",
                    data : {labCategId:labCategId,"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                    dataType:"json",

                    success:function(data) {
                        if(data){
                            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                                $('#labS').append('<option value="'+value.lab_sub_category_id+'">' + value.sub_category_name + '</option>');

                            });
                        }else {
                            $('#labS').empty();
                        }

                    },

                });
            } else {
                $('select[name="labS"]').empty();
            }

        });

        $('#labS').on('change' ,function () {
            var labSubId = $(this).val();
           $('#labT').html('');
           $('#labT').append('<option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Lab Test</option>');

            if(labSubId){
                $.ajax({
                    processing : 'true',
                    serverSide : 'true',
                    depends : ['#labC'],
                    url :'get_lab_sub_cat',
                    type:"POST",
                    data :{ labSubId:labSubId,"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function (data) {
                        if(data){
                            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                                $('#labT').append('<option value="'+ value.lab_test_id +'">' + value.lab_name + '</option>');
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#labT').empty();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        })
       $('#labT').on('change' ,function () {
            var lab_test_cost_id = $(this).val();
            if(lab_test_cost_id){
                $.ajax({
                    processing : 'true',
                    serverSide : 'true',

                    url :'get_lab_cost_rs',
                    type:"POST",
                    data :{ labtid:lab_test_cost_id,"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function (data) {
                        if(data){
                            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                                $('#testCost').append('<h5>The Lab Cost is </h5><p value="'+value.lab_test_id +'"> '+ value.cost + '</p>');
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
```